# Best way to shield microwave and cabinets from stovetop steam

Tags: cabinets, exhaust-vent, range, microwave-oven, steam

[image]

We recently installed new cabinets in our kitchen and we also had our microwave vented to the outside.

From this two problems have arisen.

- the Samsung microwave now sporadically gives a C-F0 error. I suspect that this is due to the cold temperature in the microwave meeting the warm house air (it was -30 outside this pretty cold in the microwave) causing condensation on the components inside. Like I said this is sporadic.
- as you can see from the picture, there isn’t a lot of coverage for the front of the stove. This steam goes up and hits the cabinetry above the range and microwave. I am concerned that this will cause the paint to peel

These two items are pretty concerning. I cannot find a hood that I can attach below the microwave. Is there another method I can use to better capture this steam to be properly vented outside, both protecting the microwave from damage and also the cabinets

Thanks

Comment: Is the Microwave designed for use above a cooktop? Did you meet the minimum requirements for space above the cooktop as specified by the microwave manufacturer? Does the error code appear if you run the vent fan for a few minutes prior to using the cooktop, then leave the vent fan on while using the cooktop. I think running the fan first will raise the internal temperature to room temperature before the steam hit the cold parts and condenses. Leaving the fan on will evacuate the steam.

Comment: @mikes yes - it is at least 30". It is a samsung OTR microwave. The error code occurs randomly, no real rhyme or reason to it occurring other than it is blisteringly cold outside right now. Both times it happened, the cooktop was not in use.